# Why can you only have one Invocable method per Apex class?

Tags: apex, community

Why only can one method in an Apex class be annotated with the `@InvocableMethod` annotation?

What is the reason why Salesforce is only allowing one?

Comment: I do now know _why_ we can only have one, as it is most likely related to the way the platform is built internally. But there's an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeuIUAR/allow-multiple-invocable-methods-in-a-single-class) to allow multiple invocable methods in one single class, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: is it like if more than one in same class, it is difficult for it to find one that is called

Comment: Not the *why*, but as a result of their design decisions the internal identification of the invocable method uses only the class name - take a look at the XML for your flow metadata; they would have to change this to allow multiple methods to be used.